# How to calculate number of times an element has 2 fields the same after an RDD Join (Spark)

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I started with 2 RDDs, one with userID and then "SHL .." and then one with userID and the rest of the information.

So, after joining 2 RDDs together I now have data in this format:

```
(u'5839477', (u'SHL UNRESTRICTED',(u'AGBAMA,JAMES', u'MEDALLION TAXI DRIVER',u'12/27/2020', u'08/22/2019', u'13:20')))]
```

The first field is the userID and then the next is information about them. I am needing to see
how many users have both "SHL UNRESTRICTED" and 'MEDALLION TAXI DRIVER'. I believe I should maybe have formatted the data after the .join before. The issue I'm having is being able to access the specific fields within the second field.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier expressed with DataFrames, introduced since Spark 1.6. Is there a specific reason you’re using RDDs?

If not, start working with DataFrames from the start or convert your existing RDD to a DataFrame by specifying a schema. Like this:

```py
>>> rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([("5839477", ("SHL UNRESTRICTED", (u'AGBAMA,JAMES', u'MEDALLION TAXI DRIVER',u'12/27/2020', u'08/22/2019', u'13:20')))])
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> schema = StructType([
...   StructField("user_id", StringType(), True),
...   StructField("details", StructType([
...     StructField("restrictions", StringType(), True),
...     StructField("more_details", StructType([
...       StructField("name", StringType(), True),
...       StructField("function", StringType(), True),
...       StructField("date1", StringType(), True),
...       StructField("date2", StringType(), True),
...       StructField("time_of_day", StringType(), True)
...     ]), True) ]), True)])
...
>>> df = rdd.toDF(schema=schema)
>>> df.filter(
...   (df.details.restrictions == "SHL UNRESTRICTED")
...   & (df.details.more_details.function == "MEDALLION TAXI DRIVER")
... ).count()
...
1
```

Additionally, you could consider flattening the structure, so you won’t need to dig inside the nested columns.

Alternatively, if you really must stay with the RDD, then you would access the elements as if they were nested collections:

```py
>>> rdd.filter(lambda x: (x[1][0] == "SHL UNRESTRICTED")
... and (x[1][1][1] == "MEDALLION TAXI DRIVER")
... ).count()
...
1
```

Notice how much less expressive this code is (what meaning does `x[1][1][1]` have to the reader of your code?). I definitely recommend adding names to your data structures.